# Refresh Intent String in SiriShortcut

Tags: swift, sirishortcuts

I implemented SiriShortcut in my App.

Once I created all my Intent I localized all of the Intent in two file Intent.string (English and French). But now when I add Intent the file .string does not update. It's auto generated by Xcode so the name of the strings are random like that :

```
"356cj1" = "Do my action";
```

There is a way to add the new Intent strings ?

Comment: It's not "that" random, if you open the `Intents.definition` as SourceFile (right click on it, open as Source File), you'll see it's just XML with theses identifiers. I guess that you can add the translation manually then. I didn't tried the localization, but it wouldn't suprise me that when you might need to remove the localizable (unselect the language), and reselect it, and it will appear. There might be an easier way though (I hope so).

Comment: Unselect and reselect does not change but with the Sourcefile of Intents.definition I can manually add them I will do that for the moment, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you just need to restart Xcode, it regenerate the strings files.
But be careful it will delete and replace all your strings files